# Why do I get an invalid syntax error in this piece of code, Python?

Tags: python, list, append, tuples

Code:

```
students = []
choice = None
while choice != 0:

      print(
    """
    0 - Exit
    1 - Show all students
    2 - Add a student
    """
    )
      choice = input("Choice: ")
      print()
      if choice == "0":
          print("Goodbye")
          break
      elif choice == "1":
           print("\nStudents: ")
           for entry in students:
                 email, name, number = entry
                 print(name, "\t", email, "\t", number)
      elif choice == "2":
          name = input("What is the students name?")
          email = input("What is the students email adress? ")
          number = int(input("What is the students number? ")      
          entry = email, name, number
          students.append(info)
          students.sort(reverse=False)
          student = students
      else:
          print("Sorry, but", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")
```

When I run this in the compiler, I get a syntax error for the line

```
entry = email, name, number
```

I don't know why, please tell me.

Comment: Remember that the line reported is the line where the error was *detected*, which is not necessarily the line containing the mistake.  This is because newlines are valid inside `( )` so if you have a missing `)` the compiler won't know that's a mistake until (at least) the next line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472645/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-on-valid-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing `)` on the line immediately above the line of the error.

```
number = int(input("What is the students number? ")  #here 
entry = email, name, number
```

In general, missing parentheses cause the stack trace to point to the line immediately following.